# Is there a maximum length of the expression I can use in the QGIS Querybuilder?

Tags: qgis

I use the QGIS querybuilder to filter certain species from a huge list of observed species using multiple OR statements, see image below. I wondered if there is **a maximum length that the expression builder can handle**?  I looked in the help function, on StackExchange and the internet in general, but can't find anything on the subject.

[image]

Comment: Not the answer to your question but you can shorten your expression by using the [IN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: @BERA A considered a join as a neat solution, but the filter option is much quicker to change. So I really want tot know if there are limits to the length of the query. You are of course completely right about the IN operator.

Comment: There ought not be a limit, though an infinitely long OR chain is sufficiently awful, performance-wise, that it wouldn't surprise me if there were. A lot depends on the data format -- relational databases are a lot more resilient that way.

Comment: If there is a limit, its very long. I just tried setting a query with 900 k characters. But the layer becomes so slow you cant work with it